# Why can't $\frac{dy}{dt} = ay+b$ be integrated as is?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In my ODEs course, I have seen that the general solution to the equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = ay+b$, if $a \neq 0$ is:
$$
\frac{dy/dt}{ay+b} = 1 \\
\vdots \\
y = Ce^{at}-\frac{b}{a}
$$

However, I fail to see why a solution could not be derived as follows:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = ay+b \\
\int \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int{ay+b} \ dt \\
y = ayt + bt + C \\ 
y (1-at) = bt + C \\
y = \frac{bt + C}{1 - at}
$$
I suppose this must be erroneous but I don't see where my mistake is. What is the problem with this solution? Thank you!

Comment: $y$ is a function, so $\int y\,dt$ is really $\int y(t)\,dt$, and this is not equal to $y(t)\cdot t$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, but in the other solution, the integral is $\int \frac{1}{ay(t)+b} dt$, so is that not the same?

Comment: In the other solution, the integral on the LHS is (assuming no division by zero issues) $\int\frac{1}{ay(t)+b}\frac{dy}{dt}\,dt=\int\left[\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{a}\log(ay(t)+b)\right]\,dt = \frac{1}{a}\log(a y(t)+b)+C_1$ for some constant $C_1$. The usual way of explaining it is to "cross multiply" the $dt$ and "separate variables", but this is just (I think) a confusing way of "undoing" the chain rule as I have written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ay+b \\
\int \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int{ay+b} \ dt \\$$
Your integration process is not correct
$$y = ayt + bt + C \\ $$
On the RHS, you are assuming that y is a constant which is not true in this case.